# How are methods of the Joi class called without creating an object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, joi

I tried using the Joi NPM module, in the documentation it states that it is a class, but it is used without creating a class object like `var joi = new Joi();`, how does this work?

I have a little knowledge of how a class works, it can be used by creating a class instance or by declaring the class static. Below is the code.

```
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi');
 function validation(args) {
    const schema = {
        "name": Joi.string().min(3).required()
    };
    return Joi.validate(args,schema);

 }
app.put('/api/courses/:id',(req,res)=>{
    const course = courses1.find(c => c.id === parseInt(req.params.id));
    if(!course){
       res.status(404).send('course not found...');
    }
    else{
        const {error} = validation(req.body);
        if(error){
            res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
        }
        else{
            course.name = req.body.name;
            res.status(200).send(courses1);
        }   
    }
});
```

Comment: Where in the docs? It's not on the README or API reference. Have you looked at the implementation to see what those methods do?

Comment: i did lookup but didn't get much from it as i am new to it, it will take time but i will get there soon, it would be a great help if you can help me out with this.

Comment: If you have a specific problem with your code ask about that, but if you're just curious about the implementation it's too broad for SO; it's unclear what's currently confusing you.

Comment: you see in order to access class methods one has to create its instance, but in this case the instance of Joi is not created like new Joi(), how can i use its methods directly like validate method, that is what i am asking its sort of confused my concepts.

Comment: You don't create an instance of jQuery, either, but you can still call methods on it. Or things like `JSON.stringify`. These are methods on the prototype, which can be created in a variety of ways.

Comment: thanks dave i get it now

Answer (score 0):

```
// make new component validation.js

const Joi = require('@hapi/joi');


const signupValidation = (data) => {`enter code here`
    const schema = Joi.object({
        name: Joi.string().required(),
        email: Joi.string().required().email(),
       
        password: Joi.string().required(),
        role:Joi.string(),
    })
    return schema.validate(data)
}

module.exports.signupValidation = signupValidation ; 



//now you can import in your required component
import {signupValidation } from './validation'
```